Two LazyColumn on one screen with common scroll
I need to implement two LazyComuns on one screen, one below the other (by clicking on an element in the top list, it will go to the bottom and vice versa), and the screen should have 1 common scroll, and not nested in each of the LazyColumns. If I wrap two LazyColumns in Column with modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()) - I get en error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.

The layout looks like
@Composable
fun AppListLayout(
    viewModel: AppListViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {
        ApplicationList(title = ...) // first app lsit
        ApplicationList(title = ...) // second app list
    }
}

@Composable
fun ApplicationList(
    title: String,
    appList: List<String>
) {
    Card {
        LazyColumn {
            items(
                items = appList,
                key = { it }
            ) { app ->
                 AppListItem(app)
            }
       }
    }
}


You cannot prevent a LazyColumn from being scrollable, that would defy its purpose.
If you do not want the columns to be scrollable independently then just use a simple Column instead. Then you can wrap them into another (scrollbable) Column.
If you decide that you need the LazyColumns after all you need to explicitly specify their height. By default they measure as infinitely large because it is unknown how large they actually can be (they are lazily populated, after all). That's why you get the error in the first place. By explicitly specifying their height the surrounding Column can then determine concrete values.

I already found that I can disable LazyColumn scrolling inside Card using its userScrollEnabled = false property. But then my screen only displays the top part of the content and cannot be scrolled down

Yes, that's true. Instead, use one of the approaches from my answer.

will it affect the performance and fluidity of the interface if I replace LazyColumn with Column, especially since items will be added/removed from lists in real time?

Yes, a Column is more performant than a LazyColumn because it doesn't need to determine first what items should be displayed. A LazyColumn is only more performant when you do not need to display all items at once. But as I understood the question you do want to display all items, so this doesn't apply.

As development progressed, the number of elements for lists increased to 100+, and this significantly affected the performance of UI. After loading the list items, my loader started freezing for a couple of seconds while rendering the Column items in forEach

If you have futher questions feel free to ask a new one describing your current problem.
